# Why does Eclipse not come with a compiler?

Tags: java, c++, eclipse

I'm new to C++ programming. I literally just started and know nothing about programming. I watched a tutorial online where we downloaded Eclipse for C/C++ and then installed a compiler from Equation.com and then installed JDK.

1.) Why does Eclipse not come with a compiler by default?

2.) How do you know what compiler to download, are there different types with advantages over others?

3.) Why does JDK need to be installed?

Thanks!

Comment: Different compilers have different features, different language compliance, etc. Eclipse lets you choose the compiler you want to use, instead of picking one for you. There are several compilers available to choose from. Pick a compiler that suits your needs.  Some compilers are cross-platform, some are platform-specific. Some support C++11 and later, some don't. Some have custom extensions to help with coding. And so on.

Comment: In regards to #3, I'm pretty sure that most of eclipse is actually written in Java, thus the JDK will probably required if for no other reason than to run the IDE properly in the first place.

Comment: @KookieMonster you only need the JRE to run Java programs normally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1.) Why does Eclipse not come with a compiler by default?

I am sorry if my missed anything but I don't think you need to install JDK for c++ compiler installation in your IDE. Also I am exactly sure why Eclipse doesn't come with inbuilt C++ compiler but one of the reason might be that Eclipse was mainly an IDE for Java/J2EE components so overloading IDE with C++ compiler or any other popular compiler/interpreter doesn't makes sense.Also They might user to do configure these utilities by themselves.

### 2.) How do you know what compiler to download, are there different types with advantages over others?

You can search for online repositories for installing C++ compiler (just to tool button  and search for C++ or any repositories, i think it allows English keywords for searching).

### 3.) Why does JDK need to be installed?

As already told that Eclipse was mainly built initially as an IDE for Java/J2EE development.And JDK provides tools/utilities for helping development or writing code. Those tools are like debugger,monitor etc. One last note, while writing program in Java in Eclipse you will see suggestions for what you intend to write.Those suggestions are very helpful for faster typing as well as removes headache of remembering methods etc.Those suggestions comes via JDK.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse was written originally to develop Java applications. It's highly modular and was later adapted as an IDE for all sorts of languages, but since it is written in Java, [it really only needs a JRE](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation) (runtime). If you installed a JDK instead of a JRE, then you actually took an extra (small) step and installed a compiler (JRE runs apps, JDK compiles/runs apps).

Comment: is eclipse even a good ide for C++? do you recommend something else like Code:Blocs...

Comment: Code::blocks is much lighter in size and requirements, but much, much more limited in capabilities. That said, you might not need those capabilities. I recommend trying a number of different tools, including vi and emacs, to see what fits how you think and work and see other ways to work. Steal what good ideas you can find.

Comment: I don't code in C/C++ as much these days, but if I did, I would probably use Eclipse unless I was coding for a framework/platform that made it more trouble than it was worth (like trying to develop a MacOS application or for Windows, which usually works best with Visual Studio). My familiarity of all the cool things Eclipse can do has me reaching for it most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does Eclipse not come with a compiler by default?

It does come with compiler. Not sure what are you referring to as a compiler.

> How do you know what compiler to download, are there different types with advantages over others?

If you're just starting with Programming, it's too complicated at this point to understand types of compiler and their advantages.

> Why does JDK need to be installed?

JDK stands for Java Development Kit, required for some programs that depend of Java development.